# jQuery click image, jump to select option

Tags: jquery

Hello guys I have 3 images and a select with 3 option.

The option value is the same as image alt.
How can I do it so when I click the image it takes the alt and selects the right option?

Hope you got it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the fiddle and let me know if you have any questions. the code is a bit dense

http://jsfiddle.net/phfS8/1/

```
<select>
    <option value="google">google</option>
    <option value="yahoo">yahoo</option>
</select>

<img alt="google" src="http://www.google.com/favicon.ico"/>
<img alt="yahoo" src="http://www.yahoo.com/favicon.ico"/>

$('select').val();

$('img').click(function(){
    $('option[value="' + $(this).attr("alt") + '"]').attr('selected', true);
});
```

Comment: box9's answer is much better though :)

Answer (score 6):

```
$('img').click(function () {
    $('select').val(this.alt);
});
```

Replace `img` and `select` with more specific selectors as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Box has a nice solution, but this is about 25-33% faster in firefox. You can check performance log for both selectors at http://jsperf.com/img-select00

```
$('img').click(function() {
    $('select option').eq(this.alt - 1).attr('selected', 'true');
})
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/zkebs/1/